# Illegal forward reference while calling one fuction from another function java 11 functional interface

Tags: java, lombok, functional-interface

```
@Getter @Setter
Class Row{
  private int position;
  private String name;
  private List<Column> columns;
}

@Getter @Setter
Class Column{
  private int position;
  private String name;
  private String description;
}

@UtilityClass
class CsvUtils{

   public Function<Void, Row> getCsvRow = (nothing) -> {
        Row row = new Row();
        row.setPosition(1);
        row.setName("Student Details");

        // CE : Illegal forward reference
        List<Column> columns = getCsvColumn.apply(null);
        row.setColumns(columns);
        return row;
    };

    public Function<Void, Column> getColumn = (nothing) -> {
       Column csvColumn = new Column();
       csvColumn.setPosition(1);
       csvColumn.setName("Marks");
       return csvColumn;
    };
}
```

Getting CE that is Illegal forward reference, while calling getColumn from getCsvRow.
List columns = getCsvColumn.apply(null);

Need your help to solve this problem.

One way i know that is convert functional interface to java methods then i can call method "getColumn" from "getCsvRow"

Looking for other solutions

Answer (score 1):

> Illegal forward reference, while calling `getColumn` from `getCsvRow`

Quote from the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3):

> it is a **compile-time error** if all of the following are true:
>
> - The **declaration** of a class variable in a class or interface C **appears textually after a use** of the class variable;

The compiler is telling you that you are trying to use function `getColumn` before it has been declared.

Any variable should be declared above the code that uses that variable. You should swap the order of functions to fix this compilation error.

---

There are few more issues:

- Apart from the mess causes by `Csv` prefix that appears randomly in the names, it's unclear how the result return the function that produces a `Column` object could be assigned to a `List<Column>`.
- Also, it doesn't make much sense to use a function with a void argument `Function<Void, CsvRow>` - utilize a [`Supplier<CsvRow>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) instead. Because you are not transforming the data which is the responsibility of function instead, but you need to provide an object and that is what supplier interface is meant for.